# How to add Google map with multiple marker inside custom big style notification in android

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

I want to make a custom notification with big style but i don't know how to insert google map with path and multiple marker like below image please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the google static maps API.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Markers

The link above will direct you to the markers sections. There you can read about how to use custom markers.

By using the above API you will eventually get a map bitmap, that can easily be used inside the notification.

Comment: what a about path on map??

Comment: @KundanKumarRoy It is all there in the documentation. Please refer to this section: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Paths

Comment: but this is not what i am looking for..thank for your help

Comment: @KundanKumarRoy Another option is to use the android native MapView. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView

Comment: @kundanroy Hi do you find the solution, how to show maps in notification, If you have done please guide me... Thanks

Comment: @kundanroy  hello! did you find the solution? I also need to show Google Map on my notification.